# Wrapper for standard React Native component not working in web browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, expo

In my React Native / Expo app, I wrote some wrappers for standard components that come with basic styles that I need frequently in my app. There is a wrapper for `Text` that just assigns the standard font family and font size. These styles can also be overwritten.

**The component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { rsz } from 'shared/responsiveSize';

export const SimpleText = (props) => {

    return (
        <Text style={{...basicStyles, ...props.style}}>{props.children}</Text>
    );
}

const basicStyles = {
    fontFamily: 'lucida grande, tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: rsz(16)
};
```

**Usage:**

```
<SimpleText style={{fontSize: 32}}>Hello world</SimpleText>
```

It is working fine when testing in the Expo app on my Android phone, but in Google Chrome's mobile device simulator, the basic styles just will not be overwritten by the styles for the component instance. The simulated device (iPhone, iPad, Google Pixel) does not matter.

Of course the web view is just for testing, but as I do not have another mobile device, I can not be sure that the same problem does not occur on any other platform.